# How to trim parameter values when using binding source?

Tags: c#, vb.net, parameters

I'm new to using binding source and am I looking for a way to trim the values of the parameter before I save in leading or trailing spaces into the DB. I am using stored procedures so I know I can wrap a LTRIM(RTRIM()) around the parameter, however I was looking for a way to accomplish this in my actual code.

I am setting the databinding to the actual text box: txtNarrative

```
txtNarrative.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bsDetails, "Narrative")
```

Then when I go through my save routine I am simply doing this to set the parameter value:

```
Dim cmdInsert As SqlCommand
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Narrative", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1, "Narrative")
```

is there any way to do this directly in my code here? Or would I have to go through another step and trim the txtNarrative.text before saving?

Not sure what the best approach is here,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop through the `BindingSource` or the underlying `DataTable` and modify the values in the text fields before saving the data.  If the source is correct then the parameters will use the right data.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by jmcilhinney you can loop through the rows, example

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable)
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    row.SetField(Of String)("Narrative", row.Field(Of String)("Narrative").Trim)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you both!! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each row As DataRow In dsFeature.Tables("tblFeatures").Rows
            If IsDBNull(row("Description")) = False Then
                row.SetField(Of String)("Description", row.Field(Of String)("Description").Trim)
            End If
        Next
```

This is working for me!